# APNS response packet returning the wrong identifier

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm getting an odd error when using APNS under production.

Whenever I send a notification that errors (for example the device token becomes invalid), the response packet returned is correct, except that the identifier is 1 less than the identifier I sent.  However, on production the correct identifier is returned.

For example:  I send a notification with ID 108.  But I receive a packet back:

```
8 8 0 0 0 107
```

- The first byte will always be 8
- The second byte is the status code; in this case meaning the device token isn't valid
- The last 4 bytes are the identifier

For convenience, here is Apples documentation on the subject.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW4

Is anyone else seeing this problem, or is it likely something I've done wrong.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue, but I receive completely different identifiers...